# Finding the amount of values within two numbers in python

Tags: python, list, numbers

Only started coding a few weeks ago but I've been having trouble seeing where I went wrong.

Goal is to write a function that takes a list of numbers as a parameter and returns the number of values that are within the numbers 24.54 & 47.54.

```
def count_in_range(x):
    sum = 0
    for i in x:
        if x > 24.54 and x < 47.54:
            sum = sum + 1
            return sum
```

Currently getting a "unorderable types: list() > float() error

Comment: `if x > 24.54 and x < 47.54:` should be `if i > 24.54 and i < 47.54:` because you are iterating the list of `x` with element `i` being retrieved.

Comment: Also, your `return sum` should be outside the loop.

Comment: You would never have coded this bug with meaningful variable names. For example, `list_of_numbers` instead of `x` and `number` instead of `i`.

Comment: hmm that fixed the unorderable types error but now it's just returning an incorrect output

Comment: Did you read what John has to say about moving the `return sum` outside of the loop

Comment: took return sum out of the loop and fixed the i, code works now
thanks all

Answer (score 1):

When you check the value of each item in the list, you're inadvertently checking the value of the entire list instead.

`if x > 24.54 and x < 47.54:`

should become

`if i > 24.54 and x < 47.54:`

because `i` is the variable that takes on the value of each item in the list as you iterate through.

Also, you want to move your return statement to outside the loop, otherwise the loop will terminate after 1 iteration.